# Get content of object in mouse action

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to do an interactive table, showing a popup when the user's mouse is over a cell

```html
{{#each App.PuberController}}
  {{#view App.PuberView contentBinding="App.PuberController" tagName="tr" }}
    <td>{{#if logo}}<img {{bindAttr src="logo"}} />{{else}}No logo{{/if}}</td>
    <td>{{title}}</td>
    <td>{{type}}</td>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

And,

```js
App.PuberController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [...]
});


App.PuberView = Ember.View.extend({
  content: null,

  mouseEnter: function(evt) {
    //Here I want to access content of the object
  }
})
```

I would like to have for example the name of the current object in the mouseEnter function(). Before version 1.0 pre, I could do this with

```js
this.getPath('content.title');
```

But it doesn't work anymore ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is strange that you are binding the `App.PuberController` in:

```
{{#view App.PuberView contentBinding="App.PuberController" tagName="tr" }}
```

I would have rather expected `this`, or an alias like this:

```
{{#each puber in App.PuberController}}
  {{#view App.PuberView contentBinding="puber" ...
```

Maybe your code is not exactly the reflect of this snippet? Or this should work now... :-)

---

Another remark: you should now use `get` instead of `getPath`:

```js
this.get('content.title');
```

Comment: Thanks ! My binding worked well to display infos, but not for 'get' stuff.
Yours is clearer, and works with the 'get' !